What is so interesting about the Armijo-Rule or the Wolfe-Conditions for choosing the right step size?
Right now I am taking a course on nonlinear optimization where we currently talk about step size rules(Armijo-Rule and Wolfe-Conditions).
I also had a course 1 year ago about statistical machine learning where we also discussed step size rules for optimization. There we talked about Adam, AdaGrad and RMSprop.
My question is: What is so special about the Armijo-Rule or the Wolfe-Conditions that we only talk about them in the NLO course and not about maybe better optimizers like the ones I learned in the machine learning class?
I am just a bit confused that the step size rules mentioned in these two courses are kind of disjoint. I wouldn't have expected that and so I am asking myself If I am missing something here about those two rules.
PS.: One could argue that ADAM, AdaGrad or RMSprop are more tailored to ML problems which is the reason why they are used there and not mentioned in the general context of nonlinear optimization but the objective functions in ML have a big variety and intuitively I would expect optimizers working well in ML also to work good in other fields.

In conventional nonlinear optimization, we aim to take a step in a descent direction, and use the Armijo rule or Wolfe conditions to ensure sufficient progress. In contrast, algorithms for machine learning typically use minibatch stochastic gradients, which are not necessarily descent directions.

In machine learning, we don't really care about convergence to a locally optimal solution.  In practice, stochastic gradient methods are stopped long before convergence.   What we do care about is the predictive accuracy of the fitted model, for which minimizing the training error really isn't very important.

Some communities focus on optimization methods where it is possible to prove some kind of theorem about them.  Those communities generally don't work with the best optimization methods, because the best optimization methods often are hard to prove anything about.
Some communities focus on optimization methods that work well in application domains that tend to come up in science, etc., for example optimization over a low-dimensional space, possibly with quite challenging objective functions.
Some communities focus on optimization methods that work well for machine learning, e.g., optimization in a very high-dimensional space, where the optimization problem is in some sense "easy" and where you can compute gradients but Hessians are too expensive.  This cuts out a whole bunch of optimization algorithms that might work well in other domains, as they are too expensive.
In ML, merely computing the value of the objective function (the "forward pass") is a lot more expensive than in problems from the second community.  So, line search is much more expensive for ML and is much cheaper for problems from the second community.
Methods from the second community often do a ton of computation to figure out a good direction to head in, and so then it makes sense to use some non-trivial methods to figure out how far to head in that direction (e.g., line search, Armijo rule, Wolfe conditions).  Methods from the third community don't take as long to figure out the direction to head in, and the direction changes a lot in each step, so it is hard to justify spending a lot of computation on line search.  Line search in ML contexts would be extremely slow.  Also, methods from the third community tend to focus on stochastic minibatch optimization, where our objective function has the form $\Phi(x) = \mathbb{E}_{r \sim \mathcal{R}}[f(x,r)]$, and at each step of optimization we only compute a noisy estimate of $\Phi(x)$ and its gradient, so we don't want to place too much trust in the direction from any one step, but want to average out over many steps.  Therefore it works better to do as many steps as possible and make each step as fast as possible; line search conflicts with that approach.
